# httpd RewriteRule does not add a trailing slash

Tags: linux, apache, mod-rewrite, centos

I recently made my first experience with the httpd configuration of a standard apache in a centOS installation. At the moment I fail to specify a RewriteRule that adds a trailing slash to my URLs so that the htmls in this directory can reach css and js files with relative paths (without the trailing slash, the last part of the path gets ignored: `domain.com/pizza/cs` becomes `domain.com/cs` which is bad.)

At the moment the significant part of the httpd.conf looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/pizza$ /pizza/

ProxyRequests Off
ProxyPreserveHost On

ProxyPass /pizza balancer://pizzaBalancer nofailover=On
ProxyPassReverse /pizza balancer://pizzaBalancer

<Proxy balancer://pizzaBalancer>
    BalancerMember http://localhost:1234 keepalive=On
</Proxy>
```

When I enter my URL like `domain.com/pizza` the proxy works and redirects me to my index.html there, but the index.html fails to load the js and css with relative paths, as described above.

At this point, I have no idea how to continue or fix this.

Answer (score 0):

You should append a [R] to your RewriteRule and append a trailing slash to both parameters of ProxyPass and ProxyPassReverse. That way HTTPD will add the trailing slash and then only on the subsequent request will tomcat be accessed.

Comment: I edited the httpd.conf according to your hints, but it sadly did not change anything. I am starting to think I miss something bigger.